# OpenCV - Detect (one of) multiple objects in image

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, detection, pattern-recognition

I have image with **wood trunks**.

I have to detect **each** wooden trunk individually. It looks similar like following image:

[wooden trunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c37NY.jpg)

Do you have any ideas about approaches how to do that?
Should I use Al? Or just machine learning like SVM? Or some pattern recognition algorithm?
Or I can train it.

[training dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CKQV.jpg)

I tried to detect circles/ellipses, but it doesnt have good results.
I also read that wood reflect red color.
But I dont have so much experience with OpenCV, so I dont know which approach is the best for this task.
Thank you for your help

Comment: If you have enough data, YOLO object detector would be good for that. Besides with suitable thresholding and hough transform you can get a good results too (opencv).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will look at it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think retraining YOLO seems like a good option:

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

You'll need about 2,000 labeled images, plus image augmentation. I've used this library for image augmentation for YOLO:

https://github.com/aleju/imgaug/